# Comprimir video en navegador con nextjs

Tags: navegador-web, ffmpeg

Estoy intentado comprimir un video cargado desde un input para evitar que el servidor se sobre cargue de memoria

```
export const compressVideo = async (file) => {
  const { name, type } = file;

  const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({ 
 log: true,
 corePath: "http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/ffmpeg-core.5029ecf6.js" });
  await ffmpeg.load();

  ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', 'input', await fetchFile(file));
  await ffmpeg.run('-i', 'input', 'output.mp4');

  const data = ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'output.mp4');
  const compressedFile = new File([data.buffer], name, { type });

  return compressedFile;
};
```

también configure los headers por que salía "ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not define

```
d", 
const nextConfig = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy',
            value: 'require-corp',
          },
          {
            key: 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy',
            value: 'same-origin',
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
...
```

pero ahora sale
runtimeError: abort(CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 0a 76 61 72 @+0). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.

también intente con whammy pero diceUncaught (in promise) you can't pass a duration if the fps is set

```
const compressVideo = async (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const videoElement = document.createElement('video');
    const videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    videoElement.src = videoURL;
    videoElement.muted = true;
    videoElement.autoplay = true;

    videoElement.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', async () => {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = videoElement.videoWidth;
      canvas.height = videoElement.videoHeight;
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      const fps = 30;
      const duration = videoElement.duration;
      const frameCount = Math.ceil(fps * duration);

      const whammyVideo = new Whammy.Video(fps);
      let currentFrame = 0;

      const captureFrame = () => {
        context.drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        whammyVideo.add(imageData, 1000 / fps);

        currentFrame++;

        if (currentFrame < frameCount) {
          requestAnimationFrame(captureFrame);
        } else {
          const compressedBlob = whammyVideo.compile();
          resolve(new File([compressedBlob], 'compressed.webm'));
        }
      };

      await videoElement.play();
      captureFrame();
    });
  });
};
```